# Determinant of a transposed matrix

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, determinant, transpose

The thing to prove is: $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$ for some matrix $A=(a_{i,j}) \in K^{n \times n}$.

The solution:\begin{align}\det(A^T)&=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{\sigma(i),i}\\&=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \prod_{j=1}^{n}a_{j,\sigma^{-1}(j)}\\&=\sum_{\tau \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\tau^{-1})\cdot\prod_{j=1}^{n}a_{j,\tau(j)}\\&=\det(A).\end{align}

1. Ok. In the first step we determine the $A^T$ with the help of the definition of the transposed matrix, that says $A^T=(a_{j,i})$.
2. What happens next? We say that $\sigma(i)=j, i=\sigma^{-1}(j)$ and change $i \to j$ in the product sign. But what was that? What does this substituion mean? What was actually made here?
3. In the next step we take another function $\tau$ and say that $\sigma=\tau^{-1}$ and $\sigma^{-1}(j)=\tau(j)$ in order to make the formula look similar to the definition of the determinant of $A$.

Questions:

1. Why do we make these substitutions in steps 2 and 3? Why does $\sigma(i)=j, \sigma=\tau^{-1}$ and not $\displaystyle \sigma(i)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\pi\cdot {\infty^{2}}^{log(i)}-j!$, for example? What is the idea of every substituion and why they are true?
2. We have a symmetric group. If $\sigma=\tau^{-1}$ then $\sigma$ is the inverse element of $\tau$. But we are used to name the inverse element of some $x$ as $x^{-1}$ and not as some $u$. Otherwise, $u=x^{-1}$.
   So, we name the same element with two different names and claim that we can do this. Moreover, we are sure that $\sigma=\tau^{-1}$. Actually, why these two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Note that $a_{\sigma(i),i}=a_{\sigma(i),\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(i))}$. Furthermore, since $\sigma$ is a bijection the set of all numbers of the form $a_{\sigma(i),\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(i))}$ is equal to the set of all numbers of the form $a_{i,\sigma^{-1}(i)}$. Therefore $\prod_{j=1}^na_{\sigma(i),i}=\prod_{j=1}^na_{i,\sigma^{-1}(i)}$. In the next equality, we simply use the fact that the set of all elements of $S_n$ is equal to the set of all inverses of all elements of $S_n$.
2. What we do here is simply to *use* the fact that the set of all elements of $S_n$ is equal to the set of all inverses of all elements of $S_n$. By the way, this is true for any group.

Comment: I've got it in common. Maybe the thing I am not clear with is the following: I understand that the sets are equal, but not really why the sums and products are. Taking the $3\times 3$-matrix I see that the determinants of $A^T$ and $A$ start with $a_{11}a_{22}a_{33} - a_{21}a_{12}a_{33}-\ldots$ and $a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}-a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}-\ldots$ respectivly. I see that they are equal, but it is not obvious for me, why it is true, that the $new$ sum will not produce me some term that differs from the terms of the $old$ sum. Thank you.

Comment: If two sets of numbers are equal, then the sum (or the product) if the elements of the first set is equal to the sum (or the product) of the elements of the second set. It's as simply as this.